# USB device not present on Manjaro Linux

Tags: usb, manjaro

I have tried plugging in several different USB devices (external hard drives and thumb drives), the problem is that they all show up under `lsusb` but do not show up using either `fdisk -l` or `lsblk` which is what I want to use to mount them.

Comment: same problem on 17.0.5 KDE edition on 2 different machines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26843/156608) is a working solution.
In file `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules` comment out the line

```
# Autoprobe vendor-specific, communication and PTP devices
ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}!="1", ENV{MTP_NO_PROBE}!="1", ENV{COLOR_MEASUREMENT_DEVICE}!="1", ENV{libsane_matched}!="yes", ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="00|02|06|ef|ff", PROGRAM="/usr/lib/udev/mtp-probe /sys$env{DEVPATH} $attr{busnum} $attr{devnum}", RESULT=="1", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

Than you need reload `udev` rules

```
# udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```

But for me that was not enough, so reboot seems to be required.

Related themes and links:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26842/mounting-usb-drive-that-is-not-recognized
2. [disable MTP udev rules for specific device so it can be mount as a USB Mass Storage device](https://superuser.com/questions/1206664/disable-mtp-udev-rules-for-specific-device-so-it-can-be-mount-as-a-usb-mass-stor)
3. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=119676
4. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libmtp/+bug/874293
5. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=626010

Comment: I followed the answer in the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26842/mounting-usb-drive-that-is-not-recognized) that said to add `export MTP_NO_PROBE="1"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installation (in September 2019). After a few days, after a Manjaro update, everything started working correctly.